# Can any meaning be given to this integral?

Tags: integration, functional-analysis, operator-theory, mathematical-physics, quantum-field-theory

As an example, consider the Klein-Gordon equation:
$$(\partial_t^2 - \Delta + m^2)\psi = 0. \tag{1}$$
In physics one usually starts with an ansantz of plane wave solutions so begin by writing $\psi$ as an inverse Fourier transform:
$$\psi(x,t) = \int \frac{1}{(2\pi)^3} e^{ip\cdot x} \hat{\psi}(p,t) dp. \tag{2}$$
After substituting (2) into (1) one gets
$$(\partial_t^2 + \omega_p^2) \hat{\psi} = 0$$
where $\omega_p^2 = p^2 + m^2$. Solving the above with the assumption that $\psi$ must real one gets
$$\psi = \frac{1}{(2\pi)^{3/2}} \int A(p)e^{-i(\omega_pt + p\cdot x)} + A^*(-p)e^{i(\omega_p t + p \cdot x)} dp \tag{3}$$
where $A(p)$ is a function and $A^*$ its complex conjugate.

Now in quantum field theory one does what's known as *second quantization* where the function $A$ above is replaced by an operator, $A \rightarrow \hat{A}$. Thus (3) is now an operator valued:
$$\psi = \frac{1}{(2\pi)^{3/2}} \int \hat{A}(p)e^{-i(\omega_pt + p\cdot x)} + \hat{A}^*(-p)e^{i(\omega_p t + p \cdot x)} dp \tag{4}$$
where $\hat{A}^*$ is now the adjoint of $\hat{A}$.

Expressions like (4) are very common in physics and I am trying to make mathematical sense of them. I am aware that for this all to technically work out $\psi$ actually has to be an operator-valued distribution. But putting that issue aside for now, is there any proper mathematical meaning to (4)? I am only aware of operators being involved with integrals when we use the functional calculus where we have something of the form
$$f(A) = \int_{\sigma(A)} f dP$$
where $dP$ is some projection-valued measure and $f$ some nice function. But in (4) we are integrating over all of $\mathbb{R}^n$ with what seems to be the ordinary Lebesgue measure so how can one make sense of it?

Comment: We can integrate Banach space valued functions using something like the [Bochner Integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bochner_integral). But to integrate a distribution valued function is even more complicated since these are not a Banach space. Presumably a Bochner like integral can be defined for complete locally convex topological vector spaces too. A quick google search spit out [this](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1403.5209.pdf) paper, see in particular section 7.

Comment: [This](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1403.3207.pdf) paper linked to in the paper in my previous comment also seems of interest.

Comment: @jd27 Thank you, this seems to be exactly what I am looking for. I'm surprised more has not been written on these type of integrals given how often they appear in physics.

Comment: @jd27 I have been reading about Bochner integrals more and trying to apply it to the situation in my post. Here $A$ and $A^*$ are annihilation and creation operators. What is the Banach space they belong to in order to use the Bochner integral?

Comment: It is often easier to define integrals first as weak integrals (https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pettis_integral), that is to summarize, apply first your operator to nice functions, and then integrate